# How to Upload a file to Azure Data lake store using SSIS?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-lake

What are the different ways to upload a file from Local File location to Azure Data lake store using SSIS? We have azure blob upload task which supports uploading the file to azure blob storage? Is there any way for Azure Data lake store as well?

Comment: One option is to have SSIS do an Execute Process task and run the following PowerShell command:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410042/how-to-access-azure-datalake-using-the-webhdfs-api

Comment: I can't see why this is on hold guys,@MitchWheat.  The question is quite precise, there are not "too many answers" and there is a simple answer now the Feature Pack supports this.  Please consider removing from hold.

Answer (score 2):

The [Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt146770.aspx) now has an Azure Data Lake Store Connection Manager and [Azure Data Lake Store Destination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt791776.aspx) which do what you need.  Configure the task within a Data Flow:

[image]

This was updated in December 2016 as per this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2016/12/29/update-for-sql-server-integration-services-feature-pack-for-azure-with-support-to-azure-data-lake-store-and-azure-sql-data-warehouse/